# error in Jekyll while building GitHub pages, I am not using any Sass

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

```
Configuration file: none
11
  Logging at level: debug
12
      GitHub Pages: github-pages v226
13
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.2
14
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
15
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
16
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
17
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
18
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
19
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs (Errno::ENOENT)
```